# Return distinct rows where there is at least 1 discrepancy in certain columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Assuming I had a table in my Oracle DB that looked as follows:

```
COL_A     COL_B     COL_C     COL_D   .... COL_XXX
A         1         2         1    ....
A         1         2         2    ....
A         1         2         3    ....
A         2         3         4    ....
B         1         2         5    ....
B         1         2         6    ....
B         1         2         7    ....
B         4         2         8    ....
B         1         4         9    ....
C         1         2         10    ....
C         1         2         11    ....
C         1         2         12    ....
C         1         2         13    ....
C         1         2         14    ....
```

And I wanted to find only the records where `COL_A` is the same and `COL_B` and `COL_C` are different regardless of all the other columns in the table (hence not able to just use a `Distinct` clause in my SQL) and ignore any of the records where all the values are the same for all values of `COL_A` (in this example, ALL the values for `COL_B` & `COL_C` are the same when `COL_A` = "C").

(In other words - Only return values where there is at least one difference in the `COL_B` / `COL_C` values for a matching `COL_A` regardless of the other rows of the table.)

So, I'd want my result set to be:

```
COL_A     COL_B     COL_C
A         1         2    
A         2         3    
B         1         2    
B         4         2    
B         1         4
```

So, the SQL I have written looks as follows:

```
Select b.* FROM
(
   Select a.*, COUNT(a.COL_A) OVER(PARTITION BY a.COL_A) as CNT FROM
   (
       select DISTINCT COL_A, COL_B, COL_C from MyTable) a
   ) b
WHERE
b.CNT > 1
```

Now, this works, but I'd like ot know if there is a better / more effient way to get this data??

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's wrong with the method you have?  Looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: Really?? I always tried to avoid the sub-query within a sub-query... Always assumed it bad form... Truly just trying to learn as much SQL as possible and wanted to see other ways to do it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the table to itself to find other rows that match COL_A but have different COL_B or COL_C:

```
select distinct t1.COL_A, t1.COL_B, t1.COL_C
from MyTable t1
join MyTable t2 on t1.COL_A = t2.COL_A
    AND (t1.COL_B != t2.COL_B OR t1.COL_C != t2.COL_C)
```

[See this working on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/877ab/8)

If you want the rows ordered, add an `order by` at the end.

With an index on `(COL_A)` this would perform very well. With a compound index on `(COL_A, COL_B, COL_C)` this would perform extremely well.

Comment: -1 This lists `(col_a, col_b, col_c)` combinations that occur more than once.  This does not demand that there is a different `col_b` or `col_c` per `(col_a)` group.

Comment: @Andomar right. totally missed that. What about my new answer - sexy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `exists` subquery to demand that at least one row with the same `col_a` but a different `col_b` or `col_c` exists:

```
select  distinct col_a, col_b, col_c
from    YourTable yt1
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.col_a = yt2.col_a
                and (yt1.col_b <> yt2.col_b
                     or yt1.col_c <> yt2.col_c)
        )
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/877ab/3/0)